# Ember-Cli Rest-APi Without Adapter

Tags: ajax, ember-cli, slim

Iam trying to create a Simple Rest-api with out ember data adapter. the problem is , that i can't make a ajax request with header, i means all request calls with header just stop after prefixer request ( option request).
**The Important Thing is That This Reqest Work Fine on Old Ember**

app/route/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: "POST",
            headers: { 
                "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            }
        });
    }
});
```

but is just call "Option" request, and then nothing happend. this is my option request response 
Rqeust Header:

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response Header:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 569
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2015 04:16:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
```

response server is php slim framework.